# Struggling to format variables correctly for constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, variable-assignment

I want to pass two values through a constructor, but am struggling to find a way to define my variables so that the constructor will take the values. The constructor itself must stay the same.

The constructor I'm trying to pass into is:

```cpp
playing_card(card_face const& f, std::optional<card_suit> const& s = std::nullopt) : face_val(f), suit_val(s)
{
  if (!s.has_value() && f != card_face::white_joker && f != card_face::red_joker)
    throw std::domain_error("playing card without suit must be a joker");     
};
```

And the part that is giving me errors that I am trying to pass:

```cpp
std::optional<playing_card> read_playing_card(std::istream& is)
{
  std::optional<playing_card> retval;
  
  auto face = read_card_face(is);
  //auto suit;
  
  if (face.has_value() && face != card_face::white_joker && face != card_face::red_joker)
  {
    auto suit = read_card_suit(is);
    
    if (suit.has_value())
    {
      retval = playing_card(face, suit);
    }
   
    retval = playing_card(face);    
  }

  if (!retval.has_value())
    is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
}
```

The error is:

```
a4-provided.cpp:271:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘playing_card::playing_card(std::optional<card_face>&, std::optional<card_suit>&)’

  271 |       retval = playing_card(face, suit);
```

I understand what the compiler is saying, but I'm not sure how to navigate this error in my code.

The entire clode block is here:

```cpp
//=============================================================================
#include <array>
#include <istream>
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include "a4-provided.hpp"

//=============================================================================
//
// std::optional<card_suit> read_card_suit(std::istream)
//
// read_card_suit reads a card suit from an input stream returning a
// an optional value. The return value only holds a card_suit if a valid 
// card_suit was read in. If an error occurs on the stream while reading in
// the data, then stream is failed. If the character on the stream read in
// is not a valid suit, then the character read in is returned to the stream
// using is.unget().
//
std::optional<card_suit> read_card_suit(std::istream& is)
{
  std::optional<card_suit> retval;
  auto ch = is.get();

  if (!std::istream::traits_type::eq_int_type(ch,std::istream::traits_type::eof()))
  {
    switch (ch)
    {
      case 'c':
        retval = card_suit::clubs;
        break;

      case 'd':
        retval = card_suit::diamonds;
        break;

      case 'h':
        retval = card_suit::hearts;
        break;

      case 's':
        retval = card_suit::spades;
        break;

      default:
        is.unget();                               // return ch to stream
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);      // fail the stream
    }
  }
  else
    is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);          // fail the stream

  return retval;
}

//=============================================================================
//
// Provide a simple way to generate all playing cards without requiring 
// card_face, card_suit, playing_card, and all supporting operations to be
// written first.
//
std::string all_playing_cards_as_string()
{
  std::array<char,4> const special_face{ 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K' };
  std::array<char,4> const suit{ 'c', 'd', 'h', 's' };
  std::ostringstream buf;

  // generate all numeric face cards...
  for (int face=2; face != 11; ++face)
    for (auto const s : suit)
      buf << face << s;

  // generate all special face cards...
  for (auto const f : special_face)
    for (auto const s : suit)
      buf << f << s;

  // generate two jokers (red and white)...
  buf << "RW";

  // return string...
  return buf.str();
}

//=============================================================================
std::optional<card_face> read_card_face(std::istream& is)
{
  std::optional<card_face> retval;
  
  //retrieve char from input stream
  auto ch = is.get();
  
  //peek at the next char
  auto ch2 = is.peek();
  
  //is ch EOF ? if no, continue
  if (!std::istream::traits_type::eq_int_type(ch,std::istream::traits_type::eof()))
  {
    switch (ch)
    {
      case 'A':
        retval = card_face::ace;
        break;
      
      case '2':
        retval = card_face::two;
        break;
      
      case '3':
        retval = card_face::three;
        break;
      
      case '4':
        retval = card_face::four;
        break;
      
      case '5':
        retval = card_face::five;
        break;
      
      case '6':
        retval = card_face::six;
        break;
      
      case '7':
        retval = card_face::seven;
        break;
      
      case '8':
        retval = card_face::eight;
        break;
      
      case '9':
        retval = card_face::nine;
        break;
      
      case 'J':
        retval = card_face::jack;
        break;
      
      case 'Q':
        retval = card_face::queen;
        break;
      
      case 'K':
        retval = card_face::king;
        break;
      
      case 'R':
        retval = card_face::red_joker;
        break;
      
      case 'W':
        retval = card_face::white_joker;
        break;
      
      case '1':
        //check if ch2 = 0
        if (ch2 == '0')
        {
          is.ignore();
          retval = card_face::ten;
        }
        else
          is.unget();
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);          
        break;
        
      default:
        is.unget();
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        break;      
    }
  }
  else
    is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
  
  if (retval.has_value())
    return retval;  
}

inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, card_face& s)
{
  auto face = read_card_face(is);
  if (face)
    s = *face;
   return is;
}

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, card_face const& s)
{
  switch (s)
  {
    case card_face::ace:           os.put('A'); break;
    case card_face::two:           os.put('2'); break;
    case card_face::three:         os.put('3'); break;
    case card_face::four:          os.put('4'); break;
    case card_face::five:          os.put('5'); break;
    case card_face::six:           os.put('6'); break;
    case card_face::seven:         os.put('7'); break;
    case card_face::eight:         os.put('8'); break;
    case card_face::nine:          os.put('9'); break;
    case card_face::ten:           os.put('1'); os.put('0'); break;
    case card_face::jack:          os.put('J'); break;
    case card_face::queen:         os.put('Q'); break;
    case card_face::king:          os.put('K'); break;
    case card_face::white_joker:   os.put('W'); break;
    case card_face::red_joker:     os.put('R'); break;
    default: 
      os.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit); 
      break;
  }
  return os;
}

class playing_card
{
  private:
    card_face face_val;
    std::optional<card_suit> suit_val;
    
  public:
    playing_card() = delete;
    
    playing_card(card_face const& f, std::optional<card_suit> const& s = std::nullopt) : face_val(f), suit_val(s)
    {
      if (!s.has_value() && f != card_face::white_joker && f != card_face::red_joker)
        throw std::domain_error("playing card without suit must be a joker"); 
    };
    
    const std::optional<card_face> face() { return face_val; }
    
    const bool has_suit() { return suit_val.has_value(); }
    
    const std::optional<card_suit> suit() 
    {
      if (has_suit() == true) 
        return suit_val; 
    }
    
    friend bool operator==(playing_card const&, playing_card const&);
    friend std::strong_ordering operator <=> (playing_card const&, playing_card const&);
};

std::optional<playing_card> read_playing_card(std::istream& is)
{
  std::optional<playing_card> retval;
  
  auto face = read_card_face(is);
  //auto suit;
  
  if (face.has_value() && face != card_face::white_joker && face != card_face::red_joker)
  {
    auto suit = read_card_suit(is);
    
    if(suit.has_value())
    {
      retval = playing_card(face, suit);
    }
   
    retval = playing_card(face);
  }

  if (!retval.has_value())
    is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
}
```

I have tried using manual definitions for `face` and `suit`, and I have tried adding `const` to the variables, and have tried messing with pointers and references, but I can't seem to understand how to format it the way the compiler wants.

Comment: You have to get the value out of the optional and pass it to the constructor.

Comment: Also a note: There is no point of that `if(suit.has_value())` special handling (and it doesn't even do anything as `retval` is reassigned right after the body), just pass `suit`.

Comment: thank you -- I see now i should've read std::optional definition  more carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is complaining about you passing 2 `std::optional` objects to the `playing_card` constructor when it accepts only 1 `std::optional`, in the 2nd parameter.

Change this line:

```
retval = playing_card(face, suit);
```

To this instead:

```
retval = playing_card(face.value(), suit);
```

However, that statement is useless since you are calling `retval = playing_card(face)` immediately afterwards, thus discarding the object that the previous statement had just created.  I suspect you are missing an `else` on your `if`, eg:

```
if (suit.has_value())
{
  retval = playing_card(face.value(), suit);
}
else // <-- here!
  retval = playing_card(face.value());
```

In which case, you don't need the `if` at all, just call `retval = playing_card(face.value(), suit);` *unconditionally*.

---

That being said:

`read_playing_card()`, `read_card_face()`, and `playing_card::suit()` all exhibit **undefined behavior**, as they are declared as returning a `std::optional` object, but not all of their code paths actually `return` such an object. The compiler should be warning you about that mistake.

Also, this kind of code:

```cpp
auto ch = is.get();

if (!std::istream::traits_type::eq_int_type(ch,std::istream::traits_type::eof()))
```

Can be greatly simplified to this (same with `is.peek()`):

```
auto ch = is.get();

if (ch != std::istream::traits_type::eof())
```

Or even this:

```cpp
char ch;

if (is.get(ch))
```

Also, there is no point in `playing_card::face()` returning a `std::optional` since the value being returned can never be empty.  And because of that, it doesn't make sense for `read_card_face()` to return a `std::optional` either.  Every card needs a face, if not a suit.  The caller of `read_card_face()` should be checking for a reading failure by looking at the `std::istream`'s failure state, not whether the function returned an optional (but not really!) face.

Also, `playing_card() = delete;` is unnecessary since `playing_card` has a user-defined constructor, so the compiler won't generate its own default constructor to begin with.